# Submartingale inequality

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, uniform-integrability

Let $X_n$ be a $F_n$ sub martingale. Suppose it exists an integrable random variable $X'$ such that $X_n \le \mathbb E(X' \mid F_n) \,\text{}a.s. \quad \forall n\in \mathbb N_0$.

> First I want to show that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N_0} \mathbb E(X_n^+) < \infty$.

$$\sup_n \mathbb E( X_n^+)\overset{\text{assumption}}{\underset{\text{}}{\le}}\sup_n \mathbb E\big(\vert\mathbb E(X' \mid F_n)\vert \big) \le \sup_n \mathbb E\big(\mathbb E(\vert X'\vert \mid F_n) \big)\overset{\text{tower}}{\underset{\text{}}{=}}\sup_n \mathbb E( \vert X' \vert)=\mathbb E(\vert X' \vert)$$ Since $ X'$  is integrable we have $\mathbb E(\vert X' \vert)< \infty$. Therefore $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N_0}E(X_n^+) < \infty $.

> Furhermore I want to show that for the a.s. limit $ X_\infty \in L^1$ holds.

$$\mathbb E(\vert X_\infty \vert )=\mathbb E( \vert \lim_{n \to \infty}X_n \vert )=\mathbb E( \lim_{n \to \infty} \vert X_n \vert )\le \mathbb E(\lim_{n \to \infty}\vert \mathbb E(X' \mid F_n)\vert)=\mathbb E(\liminf_{n \to \infty}\vert\mathbb E(X' \mid F_n)\vert)\overset{\text{Fatou}}{\underset{\text{}}{\le}}\liminf_{n \to \infty}\mathbb E(\vert \mathbb E(X'\mid F_n)\vert) \le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E(\mathbb E(\vert X' \vert \mid F_n))=\liminf_{n\to\infty}E(\vert X' \vert)=\mathbb E(\vert X' \vert)$$Again $\mathbb E(\vert X' \vert) < \infty$ by assumption.

**EDIT: This only holds if $ X_n$ non negative**

*If $X_n$ is negative we get* $$E(\vert X_\infty \vert )=E(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n^-)=E(\liminf_{n\to\infty}X_n^-)\le \liminf_{n\to\infty} E(X_n^-)\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}E(X_n^+)- \liminf_{n\to\infty}E(X_0)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}E(\vert X_0 \vert )< \infty$$ second last line because of $\liminf E(X_n^+)=0$

> Now I have trouble to show $X_n \le \mathbb E(X_\infty \mid F_n) \forall n\in \mathbb N_0$

An idea is to split $X_n$ in negative and positive parts and show that they are uniformly integrable. I am not able to continue here. Help is much appreciated and a comment about the attempt above is also welcome.

**Edit2**
Still one has to consider cases where $ X_n$  is negative an positive

Comment: You seem to use often $|X_n| \le |\mathbb{E}[X' | F_n]|$. Why is this the case? I would guess the best you have is $X_n^+ \le |\mathbb{E}[X' | F_n]|$.

Comment: $X_n \le E (X' \mid F_n) $ by assumption

Comment: therefore not $|X_n| \le | E (X' \mid F_n)|$ ? Maybe I will get problems if X_n is negative :/

Comment: Well, unless I am not seeing the obvious you are saying that if $-7 \le 0$ then $7 \le 0.$ Yes, exactly. That's why you need the positive part.

Comment: Well, the first step only needs rewriting. The second needs also some rethinking I believe.

Comment: it seems like the second part is doomed. Not sure how to get rid of the limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, some intuition. $X_n$ is a submartingale. This means that it tends to becoming bigger. Hence at infinity we mostly need to worry about what happens to the positive part. This can be read directly from Doob's (sub/super)martingale convergence theorem.

Now, in your first step you showed essentially that $X_n^+$ is a **uniformly integrable** sequence of positive random variables. It promptly follows from Doob's convergence theorem that:
$$
X_n^+ \to X_{\infty}^+ \text{ a.s. and in } L_1. 
$$

Finally we have to deal with the less important (yet tricky) negative part. By the submartinagle property:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_n] \ge \mathbb{E}[X_0] .
$$
From which we immediately deduce (since $X_n = X_n^+ - X_n^-$):
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_n^-] \le \mathbb{E}[X_n^+] - \mathbb{E}[X_0]
$$
Now in virtue of the first step and by applying Fatou it follows that $X_{\infty} \in L_1.$ At this point we are left with just the last step. Here we use the same treatment: we know that for $m \ge n$
$$
X_n \le \mathbb{E}[X_m | \mathcal{F}_n] = \mathbb{E}[X_m^+ | \mathcal{F}_n] -\mathbb{E}[X_m^- | \mathcal{F}_n].
$$

The first term in the sum converges in $L^1$ ans a.s. to $\mathbb{E}[X_{\infty}^+ | \mathcal{F}_n].$ For the second one we apply Fatou once again (the sign reverses the inequality).

Comment: thanks for help! Why can one assume that the first part showed that $X_n^+ $ is uniformly integrable?

Comment: Because the sequence $\mathbb{E}[|X'| | \mathcal{F}_n] = Y_n$ is uniformly integrable and $0 \le X_n^+ \le Y_n.$ If you have never seen that this implies that $X_n^+$ is U.I. you should check this from the definitions. It's straight forward.

Comment: I was missing the point that $ Y_n $ is an integrable majorante..

Comment: quote: 'Now in virtue of the first step and by applying Fatou it follows that '$ X_\infty \in L_\infty$ $\qquad$ This is not clear to me, i.e. how can we apply Fatou here to show this.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X_{\infty}^-] =  \mathbb{E}[ \liminf X_n^-] \le \liminf \mathbb{E}[X_n^-] < + \infty$ by the inequality we derived in the answer.

Comment: maybe I am brain blocked atm, but  $E(X_0) < \infty$ holds?

Comment: A sub/super martingale is always composed of $L^1$ functions.

Comment: I edited my post. Is this proof for the negative part fine? If so, all questions are cleared. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your considerations for $X_n$ negative are correct. In any case $|\mathbb{E}[X_0]| \le \mathbb{E}[|X_0|]$.